# Converting a Java object to a Javascript object using velocity

Tags: java, javascript, html, velocity

If a have a Java object (lets say a User object), and I use velocity to template the page
so I can access a field in the user object like ${user.id}, is there an easy way to convert this into a javascript object (so I can access the fields of the User object)?

I can assign a value to javascript variable like

```
var id = "${user.id}";
```

but if i do

```
var user = "${user}";
```

this isn't true:

```
 id == user.id;
```

And I would rather not have to do

```
  var user = { id: "${user.id}" ...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should transform your user object to a JSON.

You can create a utility method that uses reflection and gets each attribute from an object and put in a String. Maybe you can create an annotation to mark which attributes should be included in the JSON.

This way you send to your template something like this

```
"{id: '1', name:'stevebot'}"
```

And in you velocity file

```
var user = ${user};
```

Comment: Yeah, I think that might be the best idea. Ty for the suggestion.